# issues on layout with different iPhone devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I am building a app with storyboard. I am using the iPhone 8 template for creating my app. My design is also compatible with the other devices or it should be. I have some issues with the layout constraints. Everything works finde on iPhone 8 and iPhone 11 Pro. But I get some red errors if I switch to another iPhone.

If I start my app on the simulator, it looks normals with every device. The red errors are only displayed in the storyboard. Why I get this error even though everything is good in the simulator?

No errors with iPhone 8:

[image]

[image]

Errors with iPhone 11 template:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add some constraint limited for some devices ? With "Trait variations" ? On your VC, for every view inside who have constraints, make sure you selected "All" and not "This Size Class"
And when you said everything worked, you don't have Xcode logs with constraint errors ?

Comment: I fixed this issues. I set the width of a view to a fixed width. This was the problem.

Comment: Good job ! See you